# can i replace the php code in ajax instead of url:

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my `upadate.php` file where I am using AJAX file to pass the id to the PHP link as shown

I want to change the URL to some php code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',

    url: 'update_value.php',

    data: {

    username:username,
    email:email,
    mobile:mobile,
    uid:uid,
    },
```

I want this PHP code instead of the url

```
$id = $_POST['uid'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `username`='$username', `email`='$email', `mobile`='$mobile' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: your question is not clear? you want to redirect user to some other php page after success of ajax call?

Comment: Instead of setting both the success/error message within `#err_msg` why not create two different elements which been hidden and styles you just need to add the text.

Comment: As u can see in ajax the url directs to another page. i just want to embed that page in the same update.php. is it possible?

Comment: can i replace url with php code? is it possible?

Comment: yse like this:-`url: <?php echo $url ;?>,`  or `url: "<?php echo $url ;?>",
`

Comment: @GURURUGI but that'll show the name of the file in the browser. so (as you call it) the url is still visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `AJAX` script is in a php file then you can replace the URL using `PHP`

For example:

file_name.php

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',

    url: '<?php echo $your_url_var; ?>',

    data: {

    username:username,
    email:email,
    mobile:mobile,
    uid:uid,
    },

    success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response);

        if(response == 1){

            $('#err_msg').html('<p style="color:green">Form updated successfully!!!</p>');

        }else{
            $('#err_msg').html('<p style="color:red">Failed. Please try again</p>');
        }

    },
    error:function(error){
        alert("error "+ error);
        $('#loader-image').hide();
    }

});

});
```

If your `AJAX` is not in a `PHP` file then you need to use different approach.

One simple way can be using another `AJAX` call or `Java-script` condition to determine your URL.

For example

```
var your_url = 'update_value.php';

if(something)
  your_url = 'new_file.php';


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',

    url: your_url,

    data: {

    username:username,
    email:email,
    mobile:mobile,
    uid:uid,
    },

    success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response);

        if(response == 1){

            $('#err_msg').html('<p style="color:green">Form updated successfully!!!</p>');

        }else{
            $('#err_msg').html('<p style="color:red">Failed. Please try again</p>');
        }

    },
    error:function(error){
        alert("error "+ error);
        $('#loader-image').hide();
    }

});

});
```